# Wordpress Paid Memberships Pro, "if user is level - show: "

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

so here is the problem:

I'm using wordpress with Paid Memverships and BBpress and I want to show the Membership Level they have in the topics users info as an img . But i didn't find a thing for calling the membership level a user is on :O

Here is an excemple

```
 if ( ? is Bronze Level ? ){
 echo '<img src="images/bronze-badge.png">';
 }

  elseif ( ? is Silver Level ? ){
 echo '<img src="images/silver-badge.png">';
 }

  elseif ( ? is Gold Level ? ){
 echo '<img src="images/gold-badge.png">';
 }
else {
null;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:(maybe  helpful to you)
Suppose, 
Bronze Level's id is 1,for silver level, it's 2 and for Gold Level,it's 3...

> STEP 1 :get Data

```
$get_membershiplevel=  pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($user_ID); //will give array of current user level

$get_mem=$get_membershiplevel->id;
```

> STEP 2 : verify user level

```
if($get_mem == 1){
//Code
}
else if($get_mem == 2){
//Code
}
 elseif($get_mem == 3){
//Code
}
```

Comment: Here is Another function pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('level_id') ...thx